# An exception-safe wrapper for std::stoi

Tags: c++, error-handling, integer

[`std::stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) may throw exceptions so it needs to be surrounded by try/catch.

In applications where `std::stoi` may be used frequently, it could be useful to have a wrapper.

Is this good practice?

```
int _stoi(std::string str, int* p_value) {
    // wrapping std::stoi because it may throw an exception

    try {
        *p_value = std::stoi(str);
        return 0;
    }

    catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
        //std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        //std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Undefined error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }
}
```

Comment: [std::strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) addresses the problem in a much cleaner way.

Comment: @vnp -- agreed. And `std::stoi` is specified as if it was a wrapper around `std::strtol` that reports errors by throwing exceptions. So the way to not deal with exceptions is not to add another wrapper, but to unwrap and use `std::strtol` directly, or perhaps through a wrapper that provides the desired (non-exception) interface.

Comment: @vnp Or even the brand new `std::from_chars`.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice at all, as throw/catch make `-fno-exceptions` impossible, which defeats the purpose of your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This wrapper effectively removes some of the available functionality from [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) because its signature is

```
int stoi(const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10);
```

Because your wrapper does not allow a `pos` or `base` argument you cannot use it to give you the number of characters processed (with `pos`) nor to convert using a different base. `std::stoi()` provides default values for these arguments so you'd only have to provide them if you need the non-default behavior.

Also, you don't take the `std::string` argument by const reference like `std::stoi()` -- the string argument is probably not too expensive to copy in this context but why not accept the argument the same way `std::stoi()` does?

For completeness, I would also implement the overload of `std::stoi()` which accepts a `std::wstring` (and possibly `std::stol()` and `std::stoll()`).

I would also avoid the leading underscore, as [identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/3964927).

With these suggestions the wrapper would be implemented as

```
int stoi(const std::string& str, int* p_value, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10) {
    // wrapping std::stoi because it may throw an exception

    try {
        *p_value = std::stoi(str, pos, base);
        return 0;
    }

    catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
        //std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        //std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Undefined error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }
}
```

Comment: setting `pos = 0` yields `warning: zero as null pointer constant`. I see that this is how std::stoi is declared, but is this safe?

Comment: @Sparkler I don't see that warning even when I compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: compiler's indication is that it's coming from `[-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant]`

Comment: @Sparkler Hmm, do you get the warning even if you just use `std::stoi()`?

Comment: there's no warning when I just used `std::stoi()`

Comment: @Sparkler That's weird. Maybe your wrapper's function signature doesn't match mine somehow or you're using your wrapper differently than `std::stoi()`.

Answer (score 8):

```
int _stoi(std::string str, int* p_value) {
```

Identifiers that begins with an underscore [is reserved to the implementation](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.2) for use as a name in the global namespace.

I would expect the signature of your `_stoi` to match that of the `std::stoi` you are wrapping. So you should take the `std::string` by reference-to-`const`, take an in-out parameter to indicate how much of `str` was processed, and the base you are converting to.

---

```
    try {
        *p_value = std::stoi(str);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (...) {
        return -3;
    }
```

Instead of returning integers that represent error-codes, leverage the type-system.  There are a class of types called "either" types that let you return a result or an enumerated error.  There are also variant types that let you return one of multiple types of return or error values.

If you plan on supporting the full set of `std::stoX` family of functions and their overloads between `std::string` and `std::wstring`, I urge you to look at lippincott functions as well as variadic argument passing.

Answer (score 7):

Your function signature is misleading. You give almost the same than the std version. It's not obvious that the return type isn't the result.

```
int _stoi(std::string str, int* p_value)
 // std version, where size_t is an unsigned int
int stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );
```

So both can be called from a `string` and a `ptr to an (unsigned) integer` and return an `integer`.

- identifiers beginning by an underscore are reserved. If you want to avoid name collisions, you can (and should) enclose your function in a namespace.
- Don't pass your `string` by value, instead get a `const&` or a `string_view`
- Instead of magical return values, you can return an enum.
- Or, even better, you can, maybe, wrap the return value in a sum type like `expected` or `optional`.
- Here, if user don't want exceptions, he still have to pay for it, you are just simply hiding them. Your code isn't "exception-free", but "exception-safe".
- It would be better if internally you do the work in a exception-safe way. So, people who deactivated exceptions can still use your function.
- Which advantage versus `std::from_chars`?

Comment: Can you please explain/add link explaining "wrap the return value in a sum type like expected or optional."?

Comment: A [std::optional<T>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is a type which may contain a `T` value, or not. Look these two link to understand usage and purpose [Bartek's coding blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/05/using-optional.html) and [Modern C++](https://arne-mertz.de/2018/06/modern-c-features-stdoptional/).

Comment: [std::expected<T, E>](https://github.com/viboes/std-make/blob/master/doc/proposal/expected/DXXXXR0_expected.pdf) is a type which hold a `T` value, or an error `E`. A nice [article](https://foonathan.net/blog/2017/12/04/exceptions-vs-expected.html) about using `expected`-like type. You have a lot of implementations on [github](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=expected&type=Repositories)